how to launch multiple processes efficiently
I have a list of car models which I want to simulate by launching multiple instances of an external simulator executable. My application stores the current status of all the cars that are being simulated. Below is a shorter version of my actual application, but it compiles and also works. The issue I'm facing is during the simulation start command, which is having very poor performance because of holding mutex and launching multiple same processes for each of the car that I simulate.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <optional>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

struct CarStaticMetaData {
   char id[128];
   char model[128];
   double length;
   double width;
   double height;
};

struct CarDynamicMetaData {
   double speed;
   double fuel_gauge;
   double rpm;
   double odometer;
   int gear;
};

struct Car {
   CarStaticMetaData static_data;
   CarDynamicMetaData dynamic_data;
   std::optional<std::thread> car_sim_data_receiver_handle;
};

std::mutex car_list_mutex;
std::unordered_map<std::string, Car> car_list;

std::queue<std::vector<char>> ext_message_queue;
std::mutex ext_mq_mutex;
std::condition_variable ext_mq_cvar;

std::queue<std::vector<char>> int_message_queue;
std::mutex int_mq_mutex;
std::condition_variable int_mq_cvar;

bool ready;
std::mutex start_sim_mutex;
std::condition_variable start_sim_cvar;

void external_mq_processor() {
    std::vector<char> message;
    while (true) {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mq_ul(ext_mq_mutex);
            ext_mq_cvar.wait(mq_ul, []() {
                return !ext_message_queue.empty();
            });

            message = ext_message_queue.front();
            ext_message_queue.pop();
        }

        uint16_t msg_id{};
        memcpy(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&msg_id), message.data(), 2);

        switch (msg_id) {
            case 0x01: { // add car to the car_list
                if (message.size() - 2 == sizeof(CarStaticMetaData)) {
                    Car car{};
                    memcpy(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&car.static_data), message.data() + 2, sizeof(CarStaticMetaData));

                    std::string car_id{car.static_data.id};
                    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> car_list_lock_guard(car_list_mutex);
                    if (car_list.count(car_id) == 0) {
                        car_list.insert({car_id, std::move(car)});
                    }
                }

                break;
            }

            case 0x02: { // start the simulation
                {
                    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> sim_start_lock_guard(start_sim_mutex);
                    ready = true;
                }
                start_sim_cvar.notify_one();

                break;
            }

            default: {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

void car_simulator_data_receiver(int sock_fd) {
    char buff[1024];
    int recvd_len;
    while (true) {
        if ((recvd_len = recv(sock_fd, buff, sizeof(buff), 0)) == -1) {
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        std::vector<char> data{buff, buff + recvd_len};
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> mq_guard(int_mq_mutex);
            int_message_queue.push(data);
        }
        int_mq_cvar.notify_one();
    }
}

void internal_mq_processor() {
    std::vector<char> message;
    while (true) {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mq_ul(int_mq_mutex);
            int_mq_cvar.wait(mq_ul, []() {
                return !int_message_queue.empty();
            });

            message = int_message_queue.front();
            int_message_queue.pop();
        }

        uint16_t msg_id{};
        memcpy(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&msg_id), message.data(), 2);

        switch (msg_id) {
            case 0x1001: { // update dynamic data of the car
                if (message.size() - 2 == sizeof(CarDynamicMetaData) + 128) { // +128 because of car_id
                    std::string car_id{message.data() + 2, message.data() + 130};
                    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> car_list_lock_guard(car_list_mutex);
                    if (car_list.count(car_id) > 0) {
                        auto& car = car_list.at(car_id);
                        memcpy(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&car.dynamic_data), message.data() + 130, sizeof(CarStaticMetaData));
                    }
                }

                break;
            }

            default: {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

int create_socket(uint16_t port = 0) {
    // performs dynamic port binding by passing port number as 0 to bind function
    int sock_fd;
    if ((sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    struct sockaddr_in sock_addr{};
    sock_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sock_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    
    if (inet_aton("127.0.0.1", &sock_addr.sin_addr) == 0) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return sock_fd;
}

int get_port(const int sock_fd) {
    struct sockaddr_in sock_addr{};
    socklen_t sock_len = sizeof(sock_addr);
    if (getsockname(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&sock_addr, &sock_len) == -1) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    return ntohs(sock_addr.sin_port);
}

void start_car_driving(int sock_fd) {
    // sends a message to car simulator exe to start moving the car
    char buff[128];
    if (send(sock_fd, buff, 2, 0) == -1) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

void connect_socket(int& sock_fd) {
    struct sockaddr_in sock_addr{};
    socklen_t sock_len = sizeof(sock_addr);

    // below handshake message will be received from the car simulator to get to know the port to which it's internal network socket is bound to
    char buff[32];
    if (recvfrom(sock_fd, buff, 32, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&sock_addr, &sock_len) == -1) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (connect(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&sock_addr, sock_len) == -1) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    start_car_driving(sock_fd);
}

void start_simulation() {
    while (true) {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> start_sim_ul(start_sim_mutex);
            start_sim_cvar.wait(start_sim_ul, []() {
                return ready;
            });
            ready = false;
        }

        {
            // performance bottleneck as it involves launching a process, wait for handshake message from car simulator and creating a receiver thread for each of the car that is being simulated
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> car_list_lock_guard(car_list_mutex);
            for (auto& [car_id, car] : car_list) {
                int sock_fd = create_socket();
                int port = get_port(sock_fd); // sent as command line argument to car simulator exe to know which port the car simulator data receiver is bound to

                // launch a car simulation process which internally has a network receiver thread to receive car dynamics control commands and also periodically sends car dynamics data to the car_sim_handle thread of struct Car
                std::string command = "PATH_TO_CAR_SIMULATION_EXE which takes command line arguments namely car model and port";
                // std::system(command);
                connect_socket(sock_fd);

                car.car_sim_data_receiver_handle = std::make_optional<std::thread>(car_simulator_data_receiver, sock_fd);
            }
        }
    }
}

void network_receiver() {
    char buff[1024];
    int sock_fd = create_socket(6747);
    int recvd_len; // received data length from network
    while (true) {
        // receive network data via socket and put into external message queue
        if ((recvd_len = recvfrom(sock_fd, buff, sizeof(buff), 0, nullptr, nullptr)) == -1) {
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        std::vector<char> data{buff, buff + recvd_len};
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> mq_guard(ext_mq_mutex);
            ext_message_queue.push(data);
        }
        ext_mq_cvar.notify_one();
    }
}

int main() {
    std::thread network_receiver_th(network_receiver);
    std::thread external_mq_processor_th(external_mq_processor);
    std::thread internal_mq_processor_th(internal_mq_processor);
    std::thread start_simulation_th(start_simulation);

    network_receiver_th.join();
    external_mq_processor_th.join();
    internal_mq_processor_th.join();
    start_simulation_th.join();
}


If you want your code reviewed, you should post your actual code. It makes no sense to post “a shorter version”. If you do not want your actual code reviewed, and are only interested in why some particular bit is slow, then that is a StackOverflow question (asking for help debugging some snippet of code is literally the first thing in the CodeReview “don’t ask” list). Stripping code down to a relevant example is a StackOverflow thing. It is the literal antithesis of what code reviews are about.

I saw around 8 magic numbers in the code. Why not define some named constants instead?

Don't hold locks longer than necessary
Holding a lock will prevent other threads for progressing, so you want to keep the amount of time you hold a lock to a minimum. In start_simulation(), you hold a lock for a very long time, since you are iterating over a list and calling system() multiple times. Instead of doing all that with the lock held, consider that car_list_mutex is only there to protect car_list. So the goal is to do something quickly with just car_list, then release car_list_mutex, and then do all the other things you want to do.
In this case, just make a copy of car_list. Or as I suspect in your real program, you want to clear car_list after you started all the processes, so you can instead swap it with an empty list:
std::unordered_map<std::string, Car> launch_list;

{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> car_list_lock_guard(car_list_mutex);
    std::swap(car_list, launch_list);
}

for (auto& [car_id, car]: launch_list) {
    int sock_fd = create_socket();
    …
}

Or if you don't want to empty it, make a regular copy instead of swapping, as that might still be much faster than keeping the mutex locked while spawning processes.
Organize your code
I see lots of global variables and functions. It would be much better if you organize them somehow, for example into classesand/ornamespace`s.
There is also some code duplication that can be avoided by doing this. Consider ext_message_queue and int_message_queue, with their associated mutexes, condition variables and processor functions. At the very least, combine all the thread-safe queue processing into a thread-safe queue class.
Consider making a class Socket to represent a socket and all the actions you can perform on it.
Consider alternatives to UDP sockets
UDP sockets have some properties that are not ideal for your use case. For example, the U in UDP stands for Unreliable. That means packets can be dropped at any point in time, even if sending them to localhost. Sure, it won't happen very often, but why take that risk?
Another issue is that any process can send packets to your UDP sockets, not just the one you just started. Again, it is unlikely, but not impossible, and it's better to avoid this issue entirely.
I see two options. The first is to use UNIX domain sockets. Instead of an IP address and port number, they have a filename in your filesystem. So you can just create them in a directory that is only accessible by the current user, and don't have to worry about other users being able to access them. They also can be opened as a SOCK_STREAM or SOCK_SEQPACKET, which guarantee reliable, in-order communication (although SOCK_DGRAM is typically also reliable for UNIX domain sockets).
The other option is to use standard input and output as a communication channel with the processes you start. If you just need one-way communication, you can use popen(). It's also possible to do this two-way, but it's much more complicated. I recommend you look for an external library to do this for you, like Boost Process. The big advantage is that the communication channel exists right from the moment you spawn the simulation process, and there is no need to give them a port number or filename.
Yet another option is something inbetween the two former ones: when you fork(), the child process normally inherits the open file descriptors of the parent process. The trick is then to create a pair of already connected UNIX domain sockets in the parent, using socketpair(), then fork, and then the parent closes on eof the sockets, the child the other, and they can communicate with each other using the remaining sockets.
Handling I/O errors
In your code you check if recvrom() and send() return -1, and if so you immediately exit with EXIT_FAILURE. However, not all errors are fatal. In particular, if errno == EINTR, you should just try sending/receiving the packet again.
Also, not all problems will result in recvfrom()/send() returning -1. Consider that a packet might be dropped, or perhaps the simulation process crashed for some reason. In that case, recvfrom() will be blocked indefinitely. Even if you do use UNIX domain sockets or standard input/output redirection, then what if because of some bug, the simulation process is in some infinite loop and will never send a message?
It's best to use select() or poll() to wait for a message to arrive with a configurable timeout.
What if the simulation process sends a message of length 1, or even 0 (yes, that is possible with UDP)? You are not checking for that case, so in internal_mq_processor() you might read out-of-bounds.
